# Cakephp multiple subdomains

Tags: cakephp, subdomain

I currently have the following directory structure in my shared server

```
/

-public_html

--subdomain_1

--- app

--- cake

--- cgi-bin

--- nbproject

--- plugin

--- vendors
```

My question is:

1. What do I need to setup multiple applications each one in its own subdomain but sharing the same cakephp core for example something like subdomain1.mydomain.com, subdomain2.mydomain.com, etc with a structure such as:

/

-public_html

--subdomain_1

--- app

--- cake

--- cgi-bin

--- nbproject

--- plugin

--- vendors

--subdomain_2

--- app

--- cake

--- cgi-bin

--- nbproject

--- plugin

--- vendors

--subdomain_3

--- app

--- cake

--- cgi-bin

--- nbproject

--- plugin

--- vendors

1. Please answer by indicating which files in my app I should modify
2. Do i need to modify the htaccess files, if so, how.

I will appreciate a prompt response. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just like it says in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#multiple-cakephp-applications-using-the-same-core).

Since you can't alter the php.ini on a shared hosting server, just change the `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` constant in each `webroot/index.php` file and then you can just upload the Cake core once and have all your subdomains use that.